Regex: get all matches in between two set substrings
If I have a sentence similar to the following:
aabcadeaaabbacababe
and I want to get all of the text where it starts with c and ends with e, so that it matches like:
['ad', 'abab']
is it possible to achieve this? I have tried using lookarounds and c(.*)e, but instead of returning as separate entities in a list, they are combined into one substring that only looks for the first c and the last e.

Try to change your c(.*)e to c(.*?)e, which will make the match non-greedy.
import re

r = re.findall(r'c(.*?)e', 'aabcadeaaabbacababe')
print(r)  # ['ad', 'abab']

